# Convert XML to Object xstream ( Android )

Tags: java, xml, deserialization, xstream

I'm looking for help with the conversion of an xml to object via XStream , here is my XML

```
<main>
      <listDTO>
          <MyObject>
              <test>value1</test>
          </MyObject>
          <MyObject>
              <test>value2</test>
          </MyObject>

      </listDTO>
</main>
```

here are my classes.

```
public class First{
      MyObject[] listDTO;
}

public class MyObject{
      String test;
}
```

With xstream :

```
...
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.alias("main",First.class);
xStream.alias("listDTO", MyObject.class);
xStream.addImplicitCollection(First.class,"listDTO");

....
```

The tag `<listDTO>`  is a problem, and I can not change the XML . The classes were generated from wsdl with Eclipse .

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.alias("main", First.class);
xStream.alias("MyObject", MyObject.class);
```

First, you don't have implicit collection, but explicit one marked by `listDTO` tag. With implicit collection your XML would be:

```
<main>
    <MyObject>
        <test>value1</test>
    </MyObject>
    <MyObject>
        <test>value2</test>
    </MyObject>
</main>
```

And second error you have made was adding `listDTO` alias for `MyObject` class. That should be replaced with `MyObject` alias, since you do have `MyObject` tag defined in your XML that corresponds to `MyObject` class.